# GROUP BY with inner query? Or how to shorten the SQL query with same filters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a little program used to work with gas consumption by cars, consumption lists stored in SQL database, mainly Lists table. One of program tasks is collecting all data in some time period and showing the gasoline left at the start of that period, amount of gasoline refueled, gasoline spent throughout it, mileage and gasoline left at the end. In addition each of it is divided into three gas types.

It's been awhile since i worked on it so i don't remember the whole story, but i've ended up with such monster:

```
  SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 car_name FROM Cars WHERE car_id = l_carid) as CarName, 
(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_init FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 0 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de) as Was92, 
(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_init FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 1 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de) as Was95, 
(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_init FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 2 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de) as WasDT,

SUM(l_city) as CS, 
SUM(l_track) as TS,   

(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_fin FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 0 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de ORDER BY l_date DESC) as Left92, 
(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_fin FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 1 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de ORDER BY l_date DESC) as Left95, 
(SELECT TOP 1 l_gas_fin FROM Lists WHERE l_fueltype = 2 AND l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de ORDER BY l_date DESC) as LeftDT

FROM Lists WHERE l_date >= @ds AND l_date <= @de GROUP BY l_carid;
```

(I've cut half of fields out in example because they are basically same)

It looks horrible and dumb, i know, but i just can't come up with any structure that can shorten it. 
And i would be okay with it, but it doesn't work since inner queires are performed before GROUP BY kicks in, so i have results from very first car for all fields except for CS and TS, those work just fine.

So i was wondering:
How does one make such thing shorter? Maybe there is some way to create a field in query for each table field value? 
Maybe it'll be easier to divide it into a bunch of queries?
Is there a way to use GROUP BY with inner queries in fields?

Comment: You can try CTE to make it better. But why you use TOP 1 without ORDER BY in your subqueries?

Comment: Why does every column start with l_?

Comment: Thanks about CTE, i'll look into it. About no ORDER BY: was focused on the other problems, didn't quite think i might need ORDER BY when finding first value, since they are already ordered by list number. I use it in last bunch of fields tho. Columns start with l_ - just a coding habit to start a name with short from parent. It is sometimes easier to navigate with those prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just want conditional aggregation.  If I had to guess:

```
 SELECT c.car_name as CarName, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 1 THEN l_gas_init END) as Was92, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 2 THEN l_gas_init END) as Was95, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 3 THEN l_gas_init END) as WasDT,
        SUM(l.l_city) as CS, 
        SUM(l.l_track) as TS, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 1 THEN l_gas_fin END) as Left92, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 2 THEN l_gas_fin END) as Left95, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND l.l_fueltype = 3 THEN l_gas_fin END) as LeftDT
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l_fueltype ORDER BY l_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Lists l
     ) l JOIN
     Cars c
     ON c.car_id = l.l_carid
WHERE l.l_date >= @ds AND l.l_date <= @de
GROUP BY c.car_name;
```

Comment: Oh. I've had some tough time understanding how this stuff works, but when i finally got it, it was easy to fix it and get it working the way i need. The code was working perfectly for sums, but inner query wasn't grouping the results by cars, so instead of l_fueltype i've set l_carid in partition by, and added another same column with only difference of ordering ascending, so i could fetch the first date for the Was-columns. I don't know whether i did bad job describing my task or you did it not completely correct on purpose, but i've learned damn much from this. Thanks a lot.